# Can't Update - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Error:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Code:

```
public TEntity Update(TEntity obj)
{
    var entry = Db.Entry(obj);
    DbSet.Attach(obj);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    SaveChanges();

    return obj;
}
```

Which are the possibilities problems for this error?

I already tried remove `DbSet.Attach(obj)` like some others SO's post say to do, but occurred the same error

Comment: This usually happens when EF can't find a row matching the primary key of your object

Comment: DbSet.Attach() doesn't do anything, since setting the state of the corresponding entity object will attach it automatically if it is not tracked. Regarding your exception, EF issued an update statement (tuple identified by concurrency tokens - PK and possibly other values), but the DBS replied that no rows were actually updated. My suggestion is to either look at the concurrency token values of the entry or log the issued update statements to see mistakes there.

Comment: For both of you, I figured this out, I'll see again and compare ID values ​​again for both ... And I comment here if I've found a mistake about what you're saying to me or if I need more help, for now , thank you

Comment: I changed to add instead of update method on VS and I got an error like if the PK exists... And in fact have... So I don't know where I can looking for to find the error...